# Android: how to get the timezone string in the format specified here

Tags: java, android, datetime

How can I obtain the timezone format and return the string like so
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx - column `Time zone name`,
for example `"SA Pacific Standard Time"`

or worse comes to worst, how can I obtain it like so: `(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito`, or at least `(UTC-05:00)`

so that I can manually match it to the former String if I put them all in a map?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried?

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("TimeZone   "+tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)+" Timezon id :: " +tz.getID());
```

Result be if your device happens to be in Australia

TimeZone GMT+09:30 Timezon id :: Australia/Darwin

This should return UTC as a String and Date object. You can change the date format.

```
static final String DATEFORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

public static Date getUTCdatetimeAsDate()
{
    //note: doesn't check for null
    return stringDateToDate(GetUTCdatetimeAsString());
}

public static String getUTCdatetimeAsString()
{
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    final String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    return utcTime;
}

public static Date stringDateToDate(String StrDate)
{
    Date dateToReturn = null;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT);

    try
    {
        dateToReturn = (Date)dateFormat.parse(StrDate);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dateToReturn;
}
```

Comment: yes, it returns an object that has the string format that doesnt work for me and it also doenst have the UTC time. There is a slightly similar format, for example "Eastern European Standard Time" but in the table I included in my question, its called "E. Europe Standard Time"

Comment: Also, there is no difference between UTC and GMT. The first code example gives you the GMT which equals the same as UTC.

Comment: The second code sample has a method that will return you the UTC as a string.

Answer (score 1):

This might be irrelevant (don't know if Android fully supports java-8), but you can do it using standard java [api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Asia/Tokyo]");
System.out.println(dateTime); // 2007-12-03T10:15:30+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("(O) z");
System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter)); // (GMT+9) JST
```

Comment: If the log outputs you are showing are correct, where is the UTC formatted time, I only see a iso8601 timestamp and a GMT timestamp. Is that "+09:00" the utc time?

Comment: GMT and UTC are the exact same time. So if you must have UTC in front of it, you can just do a string replace of the GMT to UTC.